# filter array of objects based on another array of objects and return merged array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

I have an array of objects like this:

```
phoneContacts= [
{
  firstName: "aaaa", 
  lasttName: "aaaa", 
  phoneNumbers: [{id: "1", label: "mobile", number: "09121111111"},{id: "1", label: "home", number: "02188888888"}]
},
{
  firstName: "bbbb", 
  lasttName: "bbbb", 
  phoneNumbers: [{id: "1", label: "mobile", number: "09122222222"},{id: "1", label: "home", number: "02177777777"}],
},
...]
```

I want to filter it with an array like this:

```
registeredUsers= [
{
  ID: 1, 
  CellPhone: "09123333333"
},
{
  ID: 2, 
  CellPhone: "09121111111"
},
...]
```

and return this:

```
contactsMergerdWithID= [
{
  ID: 1,
  firstName: "aaaa", 
  lasttName: "aaaa", 
  phoneNumbers: [{id: "1", label: "mobile", number: "09121111111"},{id: "1", label: "home", number: "02188888888"}]
},
{
  ID: 0,            // or without ID
  firstName: "bbbb", 
  lasttName: "bbbb", 
  phoneNumbers: [{id: "1", label: "mobile", number: "09122222222"},{id: "1", label: "home", number: "02177777777"}]
},
...]
```

I want to return the first array with the matched ID field in the second array if any of it's mobile phoneNumbers matched the CellPhone in the second array.
How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const registeredUsers= [ {
  ID: 1, 
  CellPhone: "09123333333"
}, {
  ID: 2, 
  CellPhone: "09121111111"
}];

phoneContacts= [ {
  firstName: "aaaa", 
  lasttName: "aaaa", 
  phoneNumbers: [{id: "1", label: "mobile", number: "09121111111"},{id: "1", label: "home", number: "02188888888"}]
}, {
  firstName: "bbbb", 
  lasttName: "bbbb", 
  phoneNumbers: [{id: "1", label: "mobile", number: "09122222222"},{id: "1", label: "home", number: "02177777777"}],
}]

const contactsMergerdWithID = phoneContacts.map(contact => {
  const mobile = contact.phoneNumbers.find(phoneNumber => phoneNumber.label === 'mobile')
  const userfound = registeredUsers.find(user => user.CellPhone === mobile.number);
  return userfound ? { ...contact, ID: userfound.ID } : contact;
  // incase you dont want `phoneContacts` without `ID`, you can just return `false` instead of `contact` and put `.filter(Boolean)` after the `.map()`
});

console.log(contactsMergerdWithID);
```

Comment: @bekkan, this is a very simple problem, just play around with some common array functions, you can checkout MDN for that matter, they have very good documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use map and find, then destructure the resulting objects

```js
const mapped = phoneContacts.map(e => {
  return {...e, ...{id: (registeredUsers.find(r => r.CellPhone === (e.phoneNumbers.find(p => p.label === 'mobile') || {number: -1}).number ) || {ID: 0}).ID}} ;
});
console.log(mapped);
```

```html
<script>
const phoneContacts= [
  {
    firstName: "aaaa",
    lasttName: "aaaa",
    phoneNumbers: [{id: "1", label: "mobile", number: "09121111111"},{id: "1", label: "home", number: "02188888888"}]
  },
  {
    firstName: "bbbb",
    lasttName: "bbbb",
    phoneNumbers: [{id: "1", label: "mobile", number: "09122222222"},{id: "1", label: "home", number: "02177777777"}],
  },
]

const registeredUsers= [
  {
    ID: 1,
    CellPhone: "09123333333"
  },
  {
    ID: 2,
    CellPhone: "09121111111"
  },
  ];

</script>
```

Comment: Edited the answer @bekkan